# Animated gif fails to loop with jquery FlexSlider

Tags: jquery, animated-gif, flexslider

I have an animated gif that I am lazy loading into the last slide of a [FlexSlider slideshow](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/).

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {$(".slides img:last").attr( 'src', '/animation.gif')}, 5000);
```

The slideshow is set to stop on the last slide using the FlexSlider api with `animationLoop: false`

The problem is that the gif shows the animation once then stops. The gif image is saved to loop. I've also tried to reload the gif using the FlexSlider `end` callback

Is there a way to keep the gif looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the `start` callback on the slideshow to load the image and removed the `setTimeout`.